# Can you Force grow Rhubarb in JULY?

Tags: vegetables

I picked all my Rhubarb in JULY, can I restart the plant to grow more leaves this year or will this kill the plant..?

Comment: It's better not to pick rhubarb after 21st of June (after the longest day), better let it grow for next year now.

Answer (score 1):

I lived across the street from about a two acre rhubarb farm in northern IN. He would harvest it about 3 times into August. I think he said he stopped harvesting when the stores no longer wanted it because of low demand.

Answer (score 1):

Rhubarb stops growing because of high temperature and/or lack of water. Unless you can control the temperature, attempting to extend the growing season probably won't work very well.

You can't continue to force it all the year round, because it needs a winter dormant period of at least 8 weeks at temperatures below 3C (37F).